# apply_along_axis with various variables

Tags: python, numpy, apply

I have a cooccurrence matrix, a symmetric matrix (Numpy Array) in which each cell indicates the frequency of two co-occurring words.

In this matrix, I want to calculate the association strength. Which is defined as the number of times word *i* and *j* co-occur, divided by the product of *i*- and *j*'s total frequency:

```
def calculate_association_strength(self, cooc, i, j, word_occurrences):
        return cooc/(word_occurrences[i]*word_occurrences[j])
```

Here:

- `cooc` = the cooccurrence of word *i* and *j*, with size *vocabulary_size x vocabulary_size*.
- `word_occurences` = a list of length *vocabulary_size*, showing at each index the frequency of word i.
- `i` and `j` = integers, indicating the word indices.

I am looping through the cooccurrence matrix to calculate the association strength per cell. However, this approach is very slow. I am familiar with the `apply_along_axis` method. However, it is unclear how to use it for this method. Is this possible? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: show your loop code.  `apply...` only 'streamlines' the iteration on one 3+d array, and it doesn't improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to row- and columnwise divide each element of `coor` by `word_occurrences`. This can be done by simple elementwise division and broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

cooc = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
word_occurrences = [1, 2, 3, 4]

cooc / word_occurrences / np.array(word_occurrences)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Result:

```
array([[0.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.        ],
       [0.5       , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.125     ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.08333333],
       [0.        , 0.125     , 0.08333333, 0.        ]])
```

Is this what you are looking for?